# view logs from node on azure cloud service worker role

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, cloud, azure-worker-roles

I have a node server running on a node worker role at azure cloud service. when I connect to the computer with remote desktop I see the node process running on the background. how do I view its logs (console.log) ?

- there are no diagnostic configurations on the azure page or FTP access.
- its not a web-role - which means there is no IIS node running and managing the process.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer:

edit the node.cmd file that is located in the worker role folder to:

node.exe %1 %2 %3 >> logs.txt